# How to calculate the resistance (conductance) between two contacts embedded into a 3D object?

Tags: water, electrical-resistance

Pouillet's law, $R = \rho \frac{\ell}{A}$, is useful when dealing with a "column" (cylinder) of a conducting material, with cross section $A$ and height $\ell$. Using this equation has an underlying assumption: the contribution to the conductance from the surrounding environment of the cylinder is zero.

But how do I calculate the resistance (or conductance) between two given points (electrodes) that are embedded into a general shape object (for example submerged in water), assuming the surrounding environment is infinite in all directions?

Comment: Is it water that you really care about, or are you more interested in how to compute resistance when you have two electrodes embedded into a 3D object which is not a cylinder?

Comment: @DanielSank, water is just one (common) example; I'm more interested in the general case you mentioned.

Comment: You may want to edit the question to make it clear that you're asking how to compute resistance through a general shape solid. The title specifically asks about water, so people who don't know about electricity in water, but *do* know about the methods needed to answer your real question, may not click!

Comment: @DanielSank, done :)

Comment: Nice! By the way, we have a [FAQ about writing good titles](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/how-do-we-write-good-question-titles). Unfortunately I don't know how to answer this question. I hope someone else does :-)

Comment: See also [Calculating the resistance of a 3D shape between two points](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/190355)

Answer (score 0):

Pouillet's Law is valid in general, but the specific values of l and A depend in the shape and environment of the resistor. See https://www.academia.edu/1841457/The_Notion_of_Electrical_Resistance